# How do I diagnose a font rendering problem?

Tags: fonts

I recently updated my Fedora Rawhide system, and after doing so, fonts in Firefox (now 31) are ugly. But... not all of them. I traced it down to some fonts being rendered as "Helvetica" (the element inspector in Firefox tells me so), and this  being rendered with no anti-aliasing.

I don't think there is an open-source Helvetica, so something is being substituted. How can I:

1. figure out what font is actually being used,
2. discover why it isn't rendered nicely, and
3. fix the problem?

Comment: The default Firefox inspector (in Firefox 30 atleast) has [a fonts tab](http://i.stack.imgur.com/POeiu.png) - that could be used to identify the font name and possibly where it comes from.

Comment: @Wilf Yes, I'm using that -- it says **Helvetica Regular**, and under that, smaller, "system"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem with Helvetica bitmap fonts. To avoid it, I have a file `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<alias binding="same">
  <family>Helvetica</family>
  <prefer>
    <family>Arial</family>
  </prefer>
</alias>
</fontconfig>
```

EDIT: to find which font corresponds to Helvetica:

```
$ fc-match Helvetica
helvR12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: "Helvetica" "Regular"
```

This is a bitmap font. After the change in `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`, I get:

```
$ fc-match Helvetica
Arial.ttf: "Arial" "Normal"
```

a TrueType font, i.e. antialiased.

Comment: Perfect! Although substituting Arial for Helvetica might count as blasphemy; I went with MgOpen Moderna instead.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I used the easiest solution at that time (Arial was already installed for another reason). I've also found [free Helvetica fonts in OpenType format](http://www.ephifonts.com/free-fonts/download-free-helvetica-fonts) (I don't know which meaning of "free"). I haven't tried. You may need to modify the `fonts.conf` file if `fc-match` doesn't return the right one.